# How to use absolute field names in query_string search with 'fields'?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have multiple indices and I have a search that is performed globally through all these indices.

How can I tell elasticsearch to differentiate a field that is something like `article.author.name` (where 'article' is the type, and 'author.name' is a nested field) from `author.name` (where 'author' is the type and 'name' is a top-level attribute)?

So, for example, if perform such search:

```
curl -X GET 'http://localhost:9200/*/author,article/_search?pretty' -d '{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "tag": "programming"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "query": {
        "query_string": {
          "query": "John Doe",
          "fields": ["author.name"]
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

I just want to search exactly through `name` field inside `author` type. But not inside `author.name` field in `article` type. So how can I make the field names in the query to be considered "absolute" field names? Because, given it's a global search, I want to define the scope of the search by the fields being queried.

I can't simply remove the `article` string from the query URI in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **should** instead of must on bool query string.

```
curl -X GET 'http://localhost:9200/*/author,article/_search?pretty' -d '{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "tag": "programming"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
                {
                  "term": {
                    "author.name": "John Doe"
                  }
                }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Comment: You can do like that also: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/nested-query.html

Comment: This wouldn't work for me. Because I need to make full-text searches. That's why I'm using query instead term.

As for your second answer, I've been trying to avoid nested search like that, because using 'nested' + 'path' for every type that my search look through wouldn't be nice.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution that I found out is to change the mapping of my indices.

To my dismay, I set all the nested fields that I have by using 'object' type, instead of 'nested'. I did a test over here and if I use 'nested' (I obviously had to re-index my documents) I get the desired result without having to change my search query, which is what I was basically looking for. For further details: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-nested-type.html

But I must admit that recreating indices and re-indexing data is an approach that I'm not very fond of neither.